# Confused about iterating nested objects

Tags: javascript

so I have the following object:

```
{ err:
  { message: 'Validation failed',
    name: 'ValidationError',
    errors: 
     { username: 
        { properties: [Object],
          message: 'Path `username` is required.',
          name: 'ValidatorError',
          kind: 'required',
          path: 'username',
          value: '' } } } }
```

I am trying to iterate over `err.errors` and push for example `err.errors.username.message` into an array:

```
for(var error in err.errors){
  messages.push(error.message);
}
```

Doing this is just pushing null into my `messages` array. So to troubleshoot I have tried to `console.log(typeof error);` which gives me a `string`. This is what is confusing because, when I call `typeof` on `err.errors.username` it outputs `object`, yet calling it inside of the loop it produces `string`...

So what is going on here?

Comment: `messages.push(err.errors[error].message);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are accessing `key` from `object which is another`object`.`error`in`for-in`will return`key`->`username`hence you need to access that key from object and then`message`from that`username` object.

Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  err: {
    message: 'Validation failed',
    name: 'ValidationError',
    errors: {
      username: {
        properties: [Object],
        message: 'Path `username` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'username',
        value: ''
      },
      password: {
      properties: [Object],
      message: 'Path `password` is required.',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'password',
      value: ''
      }
    }
  }
};
var messages = [];
for (var error in obj.err.errors) {
  messages.push(obj.err.errors[error].message);
}
alert(messages);
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/re2xLn1u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Problems here `for in` will give you the key not data try `for of`  or `err.errors[error]`

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating `obj.err.errors.username`

```js
var messages = [];
var obj = {
  err: {
    message: 'Validation failed',
    name: 'ValidationError',
    errors: {
      username: {
        properties: [Object],
        message: 'Path `username` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'username',
        value: ''
      }
    }
  }
}

for (var error in obj.err.errors.username) {
  if (error === "message")
    messages.push(obj.err.errors.username[error])
}

console.log(messages)
```